# How to find group by field user_id and populate from another table in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I am very new in mongoDB and having issues in getting desired results.

MongoDB v : 4.2.0

I just want data in format ( anything like this) :

```
{
    array[ array[{ bot, user_response , user_id }] ] where client_id = '1234'
}
```

More explanation for output : I need an array of details of unique user chats who have submitted chats for `client_id = 1234`.

For each unique `user_id`, I need a single array containing all it's matches ( like in `group by` ).

alse populate bot from `chatSchema` tables:

```
    chatSchema {
{
    _id: {
        type : String,
        unique : true,
        required : true
    },
    content: {
      type: Array,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    response: {
      type: Array
    },
  }
}
```

My table structure is as follows :

```
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "600efa3592bd1f61be91afc5"
    },
    "bot": "4",
    "user_response": {
        "type": "button",
        "text": "Restart",
        "value": "restart",
        "id": "restart"
    },
    "user_id": "a34ba8505477",
    "client_id": "1234",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-25T17:04:53.083Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-25T17:04:53.083Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "600efa3a92bd1f61be91afc6"
    },
    "bot": "1",
    "user_response": {
        "type": "button",
        "text": "thanks",
        "value": "2",
        "id": "2"
    },
    "user_id": "8866b1863079",
    "client_id": "1234",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-25T17:04:58.053Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-25T17:04:58.053Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "600efa3d92bd1f61be91afc7"
    },
    "bot": "2",
    "user_response": {
        "type": "button",
        "text": "Girl",
        "value": "4",
        "id": "4"
    },
    "user_id": "8866b1863079",
    "client_id": "1234",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-25T17:05:01.282Z"
    },
    "updatedAt": {
        "$date": "2021-01-25T17:05:01.282Z"
    },
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: can you provide proper expected result in json format as per your documents.

Comment: @turivishal I want this type of result : https://limitless-plateau-08631.herokuapp.com/v1/chat/client?client_id=1234 exactly